# SQL Server : foreign key issue for existing data

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

I have access to database and want to copy it to my local PC (with schema and data) using Visual Studio 2015 SQL tools.

I copied schema, the database has 2 tables : `Menus` (`MenuId` is primary key) and `UsersMenuPlans` (`Breakfast` is foreign key to `MenuId`, constraint has name `FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B`).

But when I try to copy data I get an error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The target database could not be updated because of the following error:
>
> .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 37
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B". The conflict occurred in database
>   "MealGenius", table "dbo.Menus", column 'MenuId'.
>
> Last executed command: DECLARE @pv binary(16)
>
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] ([UserMenuPlanId], [UserId],
>   [Date], [Breakfast], [MidMorningSnack], [Lunch], [MidAfternoonSnack],
>   [Dinner], [MidNightSnack], [BreakfastShort], [LunchShort],
>   [DinnerShort], [Dessert], [GreenDrink], [Probiotic], [Snack1Short],
>   [Snack2Short]) VALUES (33522, 59, '20160801 00:00:00.000', 823, 536,
>   155, 943, 920, 536, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NU  (Command was truncated
>   to fit in message box.)

As I understand, some records in `UsersMenuPlans` have values for `Breakfast`, which doesn't exist in `Menus` table, `MenuId` column, therefore the SQL tool can't copy it. How can that be?

Menus table on local server has exactly the same data as on remote server:

[image]

Remote server is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64), local is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU7) (KB3162659) - 12.0.4459.0 (X64)

Script is:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET XACT_ABORT, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

DECLARE @pv binary(16)
BEGIN TRANSACTION

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] 
      DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] 
      DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__MidMo__03FB8544]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] 
      DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Lunch__04EFA97D]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] 
      DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__MidAf__05E3CDB6]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] 
      DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Dinne__06D7F1EF]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] 
      DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__MidNi__07CC1628]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] ([UserMenuPlanId], [UserId], [Date], [Breakfast], [MidMorningSnack], [Lunch], [MidAfternoonSnack], [Dinner], [MidNightSnack], [BreakfastShort], [LunchShort], [DinnerShort], [Dessert], [GreenDrink], [Probiotic], [Snack1Short], [Snack2Short]) 
VALUES (1, 77, '20090407 00:00:00.000', 32, NULL, 13, 82, 15, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] ([UserMenuPlanId], [UserId], [Date], [Breakfast], [MidMorningSnack], [Lunch], [MidAfternoonSnack], [Dinner], [MidNightSnack], [BreakfastShort], [LunchShort], [DinnerShort], [Dessert], [GreenDrink], [Probiotic], [Snack1Short], [Snack2Short]) 
VALUES (2, 77, '20090408 00:00:00.000', 32, NULL, 13, 82, 15, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] ([UserMenuPlanId], [UserId], [Date], [Breakfast], [MidMorningSnack], [Lunch], [MidAfternoonSnack], [Dinner], [MidNightSnack], [BreakfastShort], [LunchShort], [DinnerShort], [Dessert], [GreenDrink], [Probiotic], [Snack1Short], [Snack2Short]) 
VALUES (3, 77, '20090409 00:00:00.000', 12, NULL, 15, 82, 13, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans] OFF

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([Breakfast]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__MidMo__03FB8544] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([MidMorningSnack]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Lunch__04EFA97D] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([Lunch]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__MidAf__05E3CDB6] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([MidAfternoonSnack]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Dinne__06D7F1EF] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([Dinner]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__MidNi__07CC1628] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([MidNightSnack]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Error occurs on line:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersMenuPlans]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([Breakfast]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([MenuId])
```

Error is:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 380
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B". The conflict occurred in database
>   "MealGenius", table "dbo.Menus", column 'MenuId'.

**ADDED**

I have executed the script:

```
SELECT p.Breakfast, m.MenuId FROM [UsersMenuPlans] p LEFT OUTER JOIN Menus m on p.Breakfast = m.MenuId where m.MenuId is null
```

and, as I expected, some records exist (with p.Breakfast is '0' value). But how such table can exist with enabled foreign key?

Comment: What ALTER TABLE command is being executed?

Comment: I have added the script to my question

Comment: are you copying the Menus data first then the adding the constraint?

Comment: of course, Menu data list already filled http://www.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/NKuPaDySokM.html

Comment: Don't you think it would be **more intuitive** to actually **name** your FK constraints in a sensible way - e.g. use `FK_UsersMenu_Breakfast` instead of `[FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B]`  :....

Comment: @marc_s, I agree with you, but I have already DB, designed by other developers and just need to copy it to my local SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You've got data in the `UsersMenuPlans` table that the FK is intending to enforce.

Your existing data is already violating the key constraint imposed by `FK__UsersMenu__Break__0307610B`, so it can't create the constraint. Most likely, the `breakfast` column on those existing rows is either NULL or doesn't match a valid MenuId in the `Menus` table.

You'll need to deal with that data. Creating the constraint first won't help, because the issue will then become that the data won't insert due to the constraint.

It's possible that the real issue is that the Menus table isn't populated at all, which explains why the referenced value doesn't exist. In that case, the real solution is to import the Menus table FIRST.

Comment: Table UsersMenuPlans is empty, table Menus has the same records as remote server. I just want to fill UsersMenuPlans by records, the same as on remote server. There are no NULL "breakfast" rows on remote server, I checked. Probably, it has invalid MenuId there, but how it can be? Foreign key exists, but data is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just taking a backup of the database and restoring it in your LocalDB instance. It will be less pain.

If you want to work out which rows in `UserMenuPlans` don't have a row in `Menus` try something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM UsersMenusPlans P 
LEFT JOIN Menus M ON P.Breakfast = M.MenuId
WHERE M.MenuId IS NULL
```

Comment: I understand it and really some such records exist. But how such table can exist with enabled foreign key?